# How to convert tinypng compress image api to objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, curl

I want to integrate tinypng api into one of my iOS app. But I can not find any materials on their website on how to write objective-c code or convert from curl command to upload the file for processing. The curl api is below:

curl --user api:YOUR_API_KEY \
     --data-binary @unoptimized.png -i https://api.tinify.com/shrink

### I have tried on writing http post code for it,

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TINY_PNG_HOST]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:8.f];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSString *base64encodedKey = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"api:%@", apiKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];
NSString *auth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64encodedKey];

[request setValue:auth forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(obj.imageIcon, 1);

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"wigi_item_image\";filename=\"item.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@--rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request];
[dataTask resume];
```

---

but always got a failed result. I think something was wrong with uploading image through setHTTPBody method.

how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Have you considered looking into the myriad image processing libraries and functions available on iOS that can effectively replicate the entirety of tinypng without having to make a network call? Just saying - it's easier and faster if you can do it on device.

Comment: I found the same problem with the tinypng API. it's super weird. I gave up and found a solution that worked for me that involved no networking. TinyPNG is a crappy API that requires better documentation.